# How can I take a byte array of a TIFF image and turn it into a System.Drawing.Image object?

Tags: c#, .net, image, tiff

I have a `byte[]` array, the contents of which represent a TIFF file (as in, if I write out these bytes directly to a file using the `BinaryWriter` object, it forms a perfectly valid TIFF file) and I'm trying to turn it into a System.Drawing.Image object so that I can use it for later manipulation (feeding into a multipage TIFF object)

The problem I'm having is that the commonly accepted code for this task:

```
    public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
        Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
        return returnImage;
    }
```

doesn't work for me. The second line of the above method where it calls the `Image.FromStream` method dies at runtime, saying

```
Parameter Not Valid
```

I believe that the method is choking on the fact that this is a TIFF file but I cannot figure out how to make the `FromStream` method accept this fact.

How do I turn a byte array of a TIFF image into an Image object?

Also, like I said the end goal of this is to have a byte array representing a multipage TIFF file, which contains the TIFF files for which I have byte array objects of right now. If there's a much better way to go about doing this, I'm all for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** The assumption below is not correct, I had a chance to fire up my IDE later and tested with and without Write and both populated the MemoryStream correctly.

I think you need to write to your MemeoryStream first.

As if my memory (no pun intended) serves me correctly this:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
```

Creates a memory stream of that size.

You then need to write your byte array contents to the memory stream:

```
ms.Write(byteArrayIn, 0, byteArrayIn.Length);
```

See if that fixes it.

Comment: For better performance, just set ms.Length and ms.Position instead of calling ms.Write again.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I found the issue, and it was from a part of the code unrelated to the part of the code I was asking about. The data was being passed as a string, I was converting it to a byte array (this was a test rig so I was trying to simulate the byte array that I get in the main app), then converting that to a MemoryStream, then making an Image from that.

What I failed to realize was that the string was Base64 encoded. Calling `Convert.FromBase64String()` caused it to turn into a byte array which wouldn't kill the `Image.FromStream()` method.

So basically it boiled down to a stupid mistake on my part. But hey, the code above is still useful and this page will probably serve as a Google result as to how to avoid this mistake to someone else.

Also, I found an easy way to construct a Multi-Page TIFF from my byte arrays [here](http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/dotnet-csharp/70308/Craete-tiff-Image-Page-by-Page).

Answer (score 1):

All these were clues that helped me figure out my problem which was the same problem as the question asks. So i want to post my solution which i arrived at because of these helpful clues. Thanks for all the clues posted so far!

As Time Saunders posted in his answer, that Write method to actually write the bytes to the memory stream is essential. That was my first mistake.

Then my data was bad TIFF data too, but in my case, i had an extra character 13 at the beginning of my image data. Once i removed that, it all worked fine for me.

When i read about some basic TIFF file format specs, i found that TIFF files must begin with II or MM (two bytes with values of either 73 or 77). II means little-endian byte order ('Intel byte ordering') is used. MM means big-ending ('Motorola byte ordering') is used. The next two bytes are a two byte integer value ( = Int16 in .NET) of 42, binary 101010.

Thus a correct TIFF stream of bytes begins with the decimal byte values of: 73, 73, 42, 0 or 77, 77, 0, 42. I encourage anyone with the same problem that we experienced to inspect your TIFF data byte stream and make sure your data is valid TIFF data!

Thanks Schnapple and Tim Saunders!!